# launch.json for Staging environment still runs the app with Development environment

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

My launch.json for the Staging environment still runs the app with the Development environment, when I select "staging" in the vs code debugger and click run. Does anyone see why?.

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "dev",
            "launchSettingsProfile": "vepo-dev",
            "launchSettingsFilePath": "${workspaceFolder}/Properties/launchSettings.json",
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
            },
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Vepo.Web/bin/Debug/net7.0/Vepo.Web.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Vepo.Web",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "staging",
            "launchSettingsProfile": "vepo-staging",
            "launchSettingsFilePath": "${workspaceFolder}/Properties/launchSettings.json",
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging",
            },
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Vepo.Web/bin/Debug/net7.0/Vepo.Web.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Vepo.Web",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

launchsettings.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53210",
      "sslPort": 44301
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "vepo-dev": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5002;",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "vepo-staging": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://0.0.0.0:5002;",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

appsettings.Staging.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=vepo-qa-db.xxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com;Port=5432;Database=vepo_qa_db;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx;Include Error Detail=true"
  },
  "elasticEndpoint": "https://search-xxx.ap-southeast-2.es.amazonaws.com",
  "elasticIndexName": "vepo",
  "elasticUsername": "xxx",
  "elasticPassword": "xxx"
}
```

appsettings.Development.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=vepo_dev_db;User Id=postgres;Password=password;Include Error Detail=true"
  },
  "elasticEndpoint": "http://localhost:9200",
  "elasticIndexName": "vepo",
  "elasticUsername": "admin",
  "elasticPassword": "admin"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I had `webBuilder.UseEnvironment(Environments.Development);` in:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseEnvironment(Environments.Development);
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://*:5002");
            });
}
```

Just had to delete that line.